# How to get the CSS style from Inspect Element

Tags: css, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the CSS style from Inspect Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407523/how-to-get-the-css-style-from-inspect-element)

Is any tool / extension out there that helps me generating the CSS signature or style

For example:

I see a HTML object and I want to change it, I right click on my Browser ( Chrome, Firefox ) and I choose to inspect the element, there I will be able to modify any css attribute "live". Sometimes it's difficult to know which style signature would correspond to the recent changes.

```
element.style {
background: none;
}
```

My question is if there is any tool that tells you what element.style correct name would be., I think may be multiple results per style though...