# How to get the CSS style from Inspect Element

Tags: css, styles

Is any tool / extension out there that helps me generating the CSS signature or style

For example:

I see a HTML object and I want to change it, I right click on my Browser ( Chrome, Firefox ) and I choose to inspect the element, there I will be able to modify any css attribute "live". Sometimes it's difficult to know which style signature would correspond to the recent changes.

```
element.style {
background: none;
}
```

My question is if there is any tool that tells you what element.style correct name would be., I think may be multiple results per style though...

I'm already using Chrome Firebug like tools. Some elements have no style defined so it appears element.style by default when Inspecting the element. There I can start editing to see how changes would effect.

What I'm asking for is for some tool to change this default style name: "element.style" to a whole correct path for example: .superior_div_class #the_element_you_want_to_edit

Comment: Have you tried [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Firebug` for Firefox, you can inspect an element as you describe, and then copy either the `XPath` or `Css Path`. This gives you the entire path you need right from `html` down to the specific element.

[image: Copy path options]

For example say you are inspecting a link with id `myLink`. You can copy the Css Path to get something like:

`html body form table.myTable tr td a#myLink`

Comment: Thanks @KP. Is this exactly. But I think the path is unnecessarily large, is there a chance to short it to the mininum?

Comment: You'd have to manually edit the results of the copy. You could easily shorten it by removing some elements in between. If the full path is `html body form table.myTable tr td a#myLink` you could probably trim it to `table.myTable a#myLink` for example. It's really up to you. The more you remove, the less selective it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using chrome or firefox you can just click in the html and click edit and then give a class or id to the html element and it updates it live.

[image: Firebug screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, in 'inspect element", on the top where "element" and "console" are highlighted, click source and look through the nested files for the element you are looking for. I think as of today HTML files are color-coded white and CSS files are yellow, but that may change.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

- In **Chrome**, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the developers tools
- In **IE8+** hit <kbd>F12</kbd>
- In **Firefox** install the `Firebug extension`.